# FFMPEG issues for android lollipop. error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-support-library, video-processing

I was using the FFmpeg library in my application from the last 2 years and it still working fine on old version. It wont even work on android lollipop.

I was using these library before.

```
String[] libraryAssets = { "ffmpeg", "libavcodec-55.so", "libavcodec.so",
            "libavfilter-4.so", "libavfilter.so", "libavformat-55.so",
            "libavformat.so", "libavutil-52.so", "libavutil.so",
            "libswresample-0.so", "libswresample.so", "libswscale-2.so",
            "libswscale.so"

    };
```

And I have got the answer from other link that if we use these 3 libraries it will work on lollipop aswell

```
"liblicense-jni.so,","libloader-jni.so","libvideokit.so"
```

But still It didnot resolve yet.
Please check this log.

```
 ***Starting FFMPEG***
 ***error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.***
 ***Ending FFMPEG***
```

Any help or any update in library ??

Comment: I am also facing same issue. let me know if you found any solution or any other way around to resolve this.

Comment: There isnt much you can do about, its a new security feature. Even when you can change the behaviour on rooted devices http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/fix-bypassing-pie-security-check-t2797731 you should look for a PIE of ffmpeg e.g. this looks good https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find FFmpeg for Android compiled with x264, libass, fontconfig, freetype and fribidi (Supports Android L) with compile guidance [here](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android).

And if you are facing difficulty compiling it, you can use pre-compiled library [here](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android/releases/download/v0.3.3/prebuilt-binaries.zip).

Comment: You mean to say its already pre-compiled library and I just have to use it ?

Comment: Thankyou so much, this Pre-compiled lib worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Since API 21 the executables you run are required to be compiled as PIE. This is meant to improve the usage of memory as PIE or PIC (position-independent code) can be in loaded in any memory address, so that it does not overlap.

To compile ffmpeg as PIE you need to get the latest NDK, and built it. On older NDK's you had to provide the PIE option, but the new one does this by default.

Comment: I have done this but it did't work for me..I compiled x264 by android-8 platform and than compiled ffmpeg by android-16 didnot work. might be the issue is I need to compile both of these by android-16 platform.
Just look at the answer of salman he just gave me the pre-compiled link wow I just push into my project and run and it works :)

Comment: Any idea how to compile executables as PIE?